# How to disable WiFi at home?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'd like to be able to disable WiFi and cell phone at night time. Did anyone use Titan portable Wifi/ cell phone jammer? Does it work well? Does it block your neighbor's wifi as well? Or there is an options to choose from which wifi to block?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Disable your wifi and cell or someone else's?  BTW, (US) jammers are very illegal at the federal level.

Comment: Can't you just turn off your router and your phone?

Comment: Recommendations for software are best at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions, Turning off your wifi and phone without software at worse you can unplug the router from the wall and take out the battery of your phone(at worst )

Comment: They do have wall/window coatings that block all wifi and cell, but its a permanent installation.  Maybe you could put the coating on sheets of wall size cardboard, and put them up at night and take them down later.  However, this is extreme overkill.

Comment: How about just putting phone in airplane mode, and you can turn it off if you want.

Comment: Just trying to put kids to bed. Tried to unplug the router, it worked for while. Now they know how to restart it. Jammers are illegal? No wonder I have not heard of them in US. Thanks for the heads up! I guess I'll wait for Apple to come up with some kind of app that can do the trick:)

Comment: Some routers will allow you to have them turns themselves off at certain times.  You might check that in your router configuration. If you keep the configuration password to yourself, that would probably keep the kids from undoing it.

Comment: @Galinat721 , sounds like you're trying a technical solution to a social problem.  Never mind the parent/child relationship, people will always try to work around technical blocks if they don't agree with them.  See the Dancing Bunny Problem at https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-dancing-bunnies-problem/ .

Answer (score 2):

- Legally, jamming tech is mostly forbidden, but not inside in your home (for some countries).
- Jamming tech can be pretty expensive, specially if you want to cover large areas
- Yes, I have used jammers and they do work, as long as they are type-compatible. For example, a standard GSM / 3G jammer will not be able to jam 4G signals, so nowdays you'll need one that supports 4G, which is expensive.
- The range depends a lot on the model, but practically it is lower than the specified range...usually half or even less and that in open space conditions.
- Portable models will not reach very far; at most you'll cover a big room. If you want more, you'll have to get a base-station model (non-portable).
- But instead of over-irradiating yourself, why not just turn off the devices and sleep peacefully ?

Comment: Well, keeping the jamming inside your home impossible. As long as you want to receive something while the jammer is off. Otherwise, everyone’s favorite lead lining will do the tricks.

Comment: Agreed, a faraday cage setup is a good solution. Nowdays you can find anti-GSM foils, paints, wall nets...pretty much anything.

Answer (score 1):

How about to unplug your Wi-Fi router from AC? :-)
Also, doesn't configuration of your router allow to schedule Wi-Fi activity?

Answer (score 0):

**Parental Controls** - put usage timers on all the devices.

Apple has such built-in to the OS, both OS X & iOS. Search 'restrict' in Mac System Prefs & iOS Settings.

[image]  [image]

If you enable Restrictions **do not forget the passcode.**
If you do, the only way to remove it is to wipe the phone completely; restore from backup will not work.

There is probably similar on your Router/WiFi, but depends on maker.

Answer (score 0):

Some wi-fi enabled NAT routers have a button on the back that lets you turn off the wi-fi part.  If yours doesn't, you could simply buy one that does.